# Access To Message Queue System Denied Windows 7 Reading Windows 2003 - Windows 2008

Tags: c#, security, windows-7, msmq

I have an application that reads/writes from/to message queues on remote application servers.  The clients usually run on machines outside of the servers' domains/forests with no trust setup.

In Windows XP this was no problem, but with the introduction of Windows 7 it stopped working.

After some research I found the suggested Registry tweak for the server (the **NewRemoteReadServerAllowNoneSecurityClient** DWORD in **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Security** fix) and implemented that, but the software still throws an exception that access was denied to the Message Queuing system.

The message queuing system on our test server is wide open, with full control for both the EVERYONE and ANONYMOUS LOGIN accounts.

What am I missing?

Comment: I should also add that the software works perfectly on a Windows 7 machine with a user signed in in the same domain/forest as the server.  But if I sign out and sign in on a different domain or just to the local machine, access to the MSMQ system is denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been dealing with Microsoft support for a little over a week and they have confirmed that this is a bug in Windows 7 and in Windows Server 2008.  I'll come back and add more details about when they expect a fix or workaround when I have that information, but for the time-being it appears that this is simply a bug and unworkable.

Comment: The support engineer was Imelda, who informed me that the patch for this will likely be part of Windows 2008 SP3.

Comment: Not at present. We've actually given up on any systemic solution from the OS side and are basically writing away the MSMQ code for any cross-domain communication and moving to a Net.Sockets implementation instead.